Python Selenium Visa Appointment bot
I am writing a bot to get a visa appointment from vfsGlobal site with python selenium, but when entering the site, it sends a verification code to the phone number, and I want the verification code sent to my phone to be entered into the site automatically. How can I do this, I have been trying for days, I would be very happy if you could help. By the way, the site only sends codes to Turkish phone numbers, so I cannot get a foreign virtual number.

You use a service like twilio or similar that alows you to receive SMS messages via an API.
OR
Set up something that can read the SMS directly from your phone and send it to your bot. If you’re using an Android phone, you can create a app that listens for incoming messages and sends the verification code to your script using something like a local API
